# Regex pattern containing know length integer and unknown length integer

Tags: regex

I need a regex pattern to find a number like: `1234567-4`

- Seven Digit Integer
- Followed by a dash
- Followed by an integer of any length

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can the first integer be a `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first digit can not be `0`

```
[1-9]\d{6}-\d+
```

if the first digit can be `0`

```
\d{7}-\d+
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language you're using, this ought to do it:

```
^\d{7}-\d+$
```

Example and explanation: http://regex101.com/r/jM0bN5/1